# How to write an if statement that's always true without using any variables and operators?

Tags: c, if-statement

How to write an if **condition** without using variables and operators? The condition should always be true.

```
if(condition)
{
    executable statements;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written conditions without using variables and operators

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. What do you want to achieve? If your question is unclear, please edit it to reflect your intent.

Comment: I think he meant to say that he wanted to write an if statement without using any varibles and operators, but true all the time @FUZxxl

Comment: ch3rub7,thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use any non-zero number to fill the condition in if statement

> ***Examples:***
>
> **if(1)**, **if(2)**,  .....so on
>
> similarly
>
> **if(-1)**, **if(-2)**, .....so on

These would be held true for all cases except if(0)

**Reason**: You can fill the condition with any value except 0. The reason for this is  that generally in **C**,

> 0 is returned by a false condition

and so if you enter a 0, **C** skips the if block terating the condition to be false.

**so your code would be:**

```
if(1)  //I just considered 1
{
    executable statements;
}
```

Comment: How can you write it in a program?

Comment: Just write it like :        if(1){executable statements;}